# Scala : Apache DefaultParser unable to parse arg containing "="

Tags: parsing, command-line-interface

I need to parse command line args of the following format :

```
./foo --arg1 value1 --arg2 value2 --arg3 A=1,B=2,C=3
```

I am using `org.apache.commons.cli.BasicParser`

```scala
val argsArray = "--arg1 true --arg2 helloworld --arg3 A=1,B=2,C=3".split(" ").map(_.trim)

val options = new Options()
options.addOption("arg1", true, "argument 1")
options.addOption("arg2", true, "argument 2")
options.addOption("arg3", true, "argument 2")

val parser = new BasicParser
val cmdLine = parser.parse(options, args)

val arg1Value = cmdLine.getOption("arg1")
val arg2Value = cmdLine.getOption("arg2")
val arg3Value = cmdLine.getOption("arg3")
```

`arg1` and `arg2` are coming up fine as "true" and "helloworld" respectively.

For `arg3` I expect "A=1,B=2,C=3" but get "A"

Why is this happening, and what fix should I make to get expected results?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to Scala.

Comment: The parser is specific to scala/java.

Comment: Yes, but someone who knows about Scala and doesn't know this particular library won't be able to help.

Comment: Okay. Removing scala

Comment: I have noticed though that `BasicParser` is deprecated and recommended to be replaced by `DefaultParser`, maybe try that? Or see https://github.com/remkop/picocli/ and https://github.com/remkop/picocli/wiki/CLI-Comparison for alternatives.